# AspNetCore API JWT Token works in PostMan but not with HttpClient

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-webapi

I am trying to call an API with `HttpClient`, and when I call the API without the `[Authorize]` I get all of the information correctly. when I add the attribute I do get a 401 unauthorized error. The funny thing is it works correctly when I call with the Bearer token from Postman.

I have seen a few posts where they say to add `app.UseAuthentication();` before `app.UseAuthorization();` which I have done.

Below is the code that I use to call the API, something I noticed is I am calling `http://localhost:5000/api/accounts` but I am getting a response from `https://localhost:5001/api/accounts`

```
    protected HttpClient CreateClient()
    {
        var client = new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ServerAddress"]) };
        if(_securityService.HasToken)
        {
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", _securityService.Token);
        }

        return client;
    }

    protected async Task<T> GetAsync<T>(string url, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default, params object[] parameters)
    {
        using var client = CreateClient();
        if (parameters.Any())
            url = string.Format(url, parameters);
        var response = await client.GetAsync(url, cancellationToken);

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var stringContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(stringContent);
        }
        else
        {
            //TODO: Add Logger and log Result
            return default;
        }
    }
```

**Client ApiAddress**
[image: client image]

**Response Message**

[image: Response Message]

I have 2 questions here, why would this change a request uri, can someone please explain why this would work in postman, but not using HttpClient.

I thought about this and thought I should add the server code in here too.

```
        services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>()
            .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<SchedulerContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();


        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
            .AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {
                var securityKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Constants.ConstantsToAddToSecrets.Seceret));
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                options.SaveToken = true;
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
                {
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    IssuerSigningKey = securityKey,
                    ValidateIssuer = false,
                    ValidateAudience = false
                };
            });

        services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultPolicy =
                new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                    .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                    .Build();

            options.AddPolicy(Roles.Manager, policy => policy.RequireClaim(Roles.Manager));
            options.AddPolicy(Roles.User, policy => policy.RequireClaim(Roles.User));
            options.AddPolicy(Roles.Admin, policy => policy.RequireClaim(Roles.Admin));
            options.InvokeHandlersAfterFailure = true;

        });
        services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.Password.RequireDigit = true;
            options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
            options.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
            options.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
            options.Password.RequiredLength = 6;

            options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = false;

            options.Tokens.AuthenticatorIssuer = ConstantsToAddToSecrets.Issuer;
        });
```

Comment: Do you have `app.UseHttpsRedirection();` on your `Configure` method? It could be a reason for redirection

Comment: yes. I do have that. that was the issue here.

Comment: Do you use the same token for Postman and Client?

Comment: yes, it is the same token.